Functional Analysis convergence question
Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence in $B(X,Y)$ ( space of all bounded operators from $X$ to $Y$), such that $\{A_nx\}$ converges in $Y$ for every $x\in E$ and $E$ is dense in $X$. If $\{\|A_n\|\}$ is a bounded sequence, then prove that sequence $A_nx$ is convergent for all $x\in X$.
In question $Y$ is not given complete. I am able to prove that for each $x\in X$ , the sequence $\{A_n(x)\}$is bounded because of $$\|A_n(x)\|\leq K\|x\|, \forall x\in X$$ as the sequence $\| A_n\| $ is given bounded. Let $x\in X$, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ form $E $ such that $x_n \to x$. How to show that sequence $\{ f_n(x)\}$ is convergent? Thank you.

That's not true. Let $X$ be $c_0$ (space of sequences with limit $0$ with supremum norm), $Y$ be $c_{00}$ (space of sequences with finitely many non-zero terms with supremum norm), $A_n$ be projection to first $n$ coordinates, and $E$ be set of sequences with finitely many non-zero terms.
Then for $x \in E$, $A_n x$ converges (it's eventually stationary). And $\|A_n\| = 1$. But, for example, $A_n(1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots)$ doesn't converge in $Y$.
We can easily prove that $A_n x$ is Cauchy: let $y \in E$, be such that $\|x - y\| < \epsilon$, then $\|A_n x - A_m x\| \leq \|A_n x - A_n y\| + \|A_n y - A_m y\| + \|A_m y - A_m x\| < 2K\epsilon + \|A_n y - A_m y\|$, which can be made arbitrary small. But if $Y$ isn't complete, it can be Cauchy but not convergent, as example above shows.

Thank you very much ...
